# How to get a pop up in QGIS when clicking on points on a map

Tags: qgis, popup, infowindow, photos

I have QGIS V 2.12.0 and am an absolute novice, doing some volunteer work for a charity.

I have created a map with added Delimited Text Layer.  This references Buildings by Latitude and Longitude from an imported CSV file (an Excel file).  This all works fine on different maps.  I would like to to be able to click on the points on the map and for information to be displayed in a box or window, such as the Building's details and address which has been successfully imported in the Attribute Table and then hopefully with this display a thumbnail image, but I don't know how to do this.

I have seen a similar post regarding clicking points and images then popping up, but the advice given related to creating a point file. Can I use my Delimited Text Layer, or do I need to do something else?  I have no idea as yet how to get the data from my CSV file into a point file if this is the recommended route.

Comment: to get your csv into shapefile/mapinfo point format simply right-click the layer in and 'save layer as'

Answer (score 6):

Ok two things here I think.  Getting information for a point and creating a shapefile.

1. **Information.**

There is a tool called "Identify Features" which is a point that allows you to bring up a window with the attributes of that feature.  It is location in the "View" menu or via the button in the attached image (left button with the 'i').  The only trick is that I think it defaults to only working on a layer you have selected however by right clicking you can do it for other layers.  This does work with csv files.

The way to get information on non-selected or multiple layers is to use the right click with the same function and selecting "Identify All" which opens a slightly different window with attribute information and allows you to change which layers you want information for in the "Mode" menu.

[image: Identify Features button]

2. **Save a point layer = create shapfile.**

It can be helpful to convert your csv data into a shapefile because you can then edit it and add fields and do calculations (and probably some other things too).  To do this you just right click on the layer in the Layers side bar and select Save As... In the dialogue window you select a Format (which will usually be ESRI Shapefile), select a name and location and OK.  You can select the "Add saved file to map" option or add it using the "Add Vector Layer" button/function.